# How to fix the footer at the bottom of the page and How to display extra books another page in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, sass

I am developing a dashboard UI , and it contains child component like DisplayBooks.vue , it should display the books from the backend . i want to add a footer to my dashboard page at the bottom it should fix it should be adjusted based on the books rows ,and i want to provide 3 rows only and remaining books should be in next page [[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4V4mk.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4V4mk.png) and footer should be fixed at bottom of the page , [[i am getting like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9qU8.png) ][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9qU8.png),i want to add footer after 3 rows of books and remaining books should display in next page,How to acheive this thing please help me to fix this issue

`Dashboard.vue`

```
<template>
<div class="main">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <img src="../assets/education.png" alt="notFound" class="education-image" />
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
                <p class="brand">Bookstore</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="input-group">
            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
            <div class="form-outline">
                <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder='search...' />
            </div>
        </div>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="right-bar">
            <li><a> <i class="far fa-user"></i></a></li>
            <p class="profile-content">profile</p>
            <li><a><i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i></a></li>
            <p class="cart-content">cart</p>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="mid-body">
        <h6>Books<span class="items">(128items)</span></h6>
        <select  class="options">
            <option value="volvo">sort by relevance</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <DisplayBooks />
   
</div>
</template>

<script>
import DisplayBooks from './DisplayBooks.vue'
export default {
    components: {
        DisplayBooks
    },
    data() {
        return {
            brand:'Bookstore',
        }
    },

}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import "colors";
.navbar-default {
    background: $redish_brown;
    height: 60px;
}
li .brand{
   
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: -1210px;
    width: 91px;
    height: 26px;
    text-align: left;
    font: normal normal normal 18px/26px Roboto;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: $pale_white;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    opacity: 1;
}
img {
    background: transparent 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    opacity: 1;
    width: 31px;
    height: 24px;
    margin-top: -12px;
    margin-left: 194px;
}
.input-group{
    margin-left:395px;
}
input[type="search"]{
    width: 490px;
    height: 33px;
    margin-top:-40px;
    background: #FCFCFC 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-left:3px;
    opacity: 1;
}


.input-group {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; // to center the icon vertically
}

.input-group .fas {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 8px;

}
.fa-search{
    margin-top:-40px;
     opacity: 1;
}
.input-group input[type="search"] {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
}
a i{
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  color:$white;
  opacity: 1;
}
 #right-bar{
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  right: 0;
  flex-direction: row !important;  
  gap: 3.5rem;
  margin-right: 15rem;
  margin-top: 20px;

}
.profile-content{
  margin-top:15px;
  margin-left:-86px;
  letter-spacing: 0.45px;
  color: $pale_white;
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
}
.cart-content{
  margin-top:15px;
  margin-left:-75px;
  letter-spacing: 0.75px;
  color: $pale_white;
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
}
.mid-body {
  display:flex;
}
.options{
  margin-top:26px;
  margin-left:69%;
  height:25px;
}
h6{
  margin-top:26px;
  margin-left:110px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
 font-size: larger;
 font: 20px;
}
.items{
  color:$grey;
  font-size: 12px;
}
</style>
```

`DisplayBooks.vue`

```
<template>
<div class="carddisplay-section">
    <div v-for="book in books" :key="book.id" class="card">
        <div class="image-section">
            <div class="image-container">
                <img v-bind:src="book.file" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="title-section">
            {{book.name}}
        </div>
        <div class="author-section">
            by {{book.author}}
        </div>
        <div class="price-section">
            Rs. {{book.price}}<label class="default">(2000)</label>
            <button v-if="flag" class="btn-grp" type="submit" @click="handlesubmit();Togglebtn();">close</button>
        </div>
        <div class="button-groups">
            <button type="button" class="AddBag">Add to Bag</button>
            <button type="button" class="wishlist">wishlist</button>
        </div>
    </div>
     <footer >
       Copyright © 2020, Bookstore Private Limited. All Rights Reserved
    </footer>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import service from '../service/User'
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            authorPrefix: 'by',
            pricePrefix: 'Rs.',
            defaultStrikePrice: '(2000)',
            buttonValue: 'close',
            flag: true,
            books: [{
                id: 0,
                file: 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41MdP5Tn0wL._SX258_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg',
                name: 'Dont Make me think',
                author: 'sai',
                price: '1500'
            }, ]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        Togglebtn() {
            this.flag = !this.flag;
        },
        handlesubmit() {
            service.userDisplayBooks().then(response => {
                this.books.push(...response.data);
            })
        },
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import "colors";
.carddisplay-section {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: space-around;
    gap: 10px;
}
.card:hover{
    box-shadow:0.6px 0.6px 0.6px 0.6px rgb(173, 206, 206);
}
.card {
    margin-top: 55px;
    margin-left: 110px;
    background:$pink;
    // width: 235px;
    // height: 275px;
    width: 235px;
height: 315px;
    background: $pale_white 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    border: 1px solid $border_clr;
    border-radius: 3px;
    opacity: 1;
}

.image-section {
    width: 233px;
    height: 172px;
    background: #F5F5F5 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    border-radius: 2px 2px 0px 0px;
    opacity: 1;
}

img{
    margin-left: 67px;
    margin-top: 17px;
    width: 105px;
    height: 135px;
    opacity: 1;
    border:none;
}

.title-section {
    text-align: left;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/19px Roboto;
    letter-spacing: 0.2px;
    color: $light_black;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    width: 130px;
    height: 19px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.author-section {
    text-align: left;
    font: normal normal normal 13px/13px Roboto;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: $light_grey;
    opacity: 1;
    width: 123px;
    height: 13px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 7px;
}

.price-section {
    text-align: left;
    font: normal normal bold 12px/16px Roboto;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: $light_black;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: 20px;
    height: 16px;
    margin-top: 26px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;

}

label {
    text-decoration-line: line-through;
    font: normal normal normal 10px/13px Roboto;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: $light_grey;
    opacity: 1;
    width: 36px;
    height: 13px;
    margin-top: 2.5px;
    margin-left: 1em;
}

button[type="submit"] {
    border: none;
    padding-left: 65px;
    background: none;
}
.button-groups{
    display:flex;
    margin-top:8px;
}
.AddBag{
    background: #A03037 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    border-radius: 2px;
    opacity: 1;
    width: 93px;
    height: 29px;
    margin-left:20px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: small;
}
.wishlist{
    margin-left:4px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: small;
    border: 1px solid #9D9D9D;
border-radius: 2px;
opacity: 1;
color: #0A0102;
width:93px;
}

   
</style>
```